# symfony2.3 doesn't load messages yml for one locale (other locales are working fine)

Tags: php, symfony, yaml, symfony-2.3

I've a symfony 2.3 application with translations for it, es, fr, pt; now I've to add en_ZA locale and so I've created messages.en.yml

Unfortunately translation isn't working for en_ZA, but it's working for other locales.

I've tried renaming my file in messages.en_ZA.yml but it doesn't work.

Have you ever faced a issue like this? Can you please help me figuring out how to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot

---

News_PLURAL should be translated...

[image: en_ZA][image: pt][image: fr][image: es]

Comment: After creating/renaming translation files you have to `cache:clear`. Did you do that? :)

Comment: Did you configured your browser to request `en_ZA`? Is `en` or `en_ZA` defined as `framework.default_locale`? Have you checked that `News_PLURAL` is correctly formatted?

Comment: you're right Jovan :) thanks a lot!